# Linking rooms using dictionaries from a random text file - Adventure game

Tags: python, class, dictionary

i am currently creating an adventure game in which you move through rooms of a dungeon via typing commands into input ("NORTH","SOUTH"...). So i am trying to link each room together using a dictionary such that i can use the key of "North", "South"etc to move through these rooms. But i cant seem to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you are stuck on. Will each room have a dictionary saying what it's linked to, using key like "North" to a value which is another room?

Comment: yes sorry, each room will have a dictionary of what it is linked to, and the direction of  its exits to to other rooms. The file is given in the format "START > DIRECTION > DESTINATION", with each separate path ("START > DIRECTION > DESTINATION") given on a seperate line

Comment: put all information in question, not in comment. They will be more readable and yoi can format them.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea has several advantages in disadvantages:

If you want a classical 'roguelike-ish' movement (in a 2d-grid with some kind of tiles), you will have many problems with graph dungeon representation (actually you are using graphs now). Let's see on this dungeon:

```
ROOM1 > ROOM2 > NORTH
ROOM2 > ROOM3 > NORTH
ROOM3 > ROOM1 > NORTH
```

You will have a room ring. It is not good but you can do something like it:

```
ROOM1 > ROOM2 > NORTH
ROOM1 > ROOM2 > SOUTH
```

Which is really confusing because you can move in different directions and go to one room. To prevent these cases by design you can represent your dungeon as a fair 2d-grid, like it:

```
rooms_mask = [
    [0,1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,0,1],
    [0,0,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0]
]
```

And your actions will just add or sub a 1 from the x or y coordinate of the current position. Here is the simple example code:

```
class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        if self.y < 3:
            return 'It is a dark and gloomy room: ({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)
        else:
            return 'It is a light and shining room: ({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

rooms_mask = [
    [0,1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,0,1],
    [0,0,1,1,1],
    [1,1,1,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0,0]
]

rooms = [[Room(j, i) for j, _ in enumerate(rm)] for i, rm in enumerate(rooms_mask)]

x = 2
y = 2

while True:
    action = input()
    if action == 'q':
        break
    elif action == 'n':
        if y > 0 and rooms_mask[y-1][x] == 1:
            y -= 1
            print(rooms[y][x])
    elif action == 's':
        if y < len(rooms_mask) - 1 and rooms_mask[y+1][x] == 1:
            y += 1
            print(rooms[y][x])
    elif action == 'e':
        if x < len(rooms[0]) - 1 and rooms_mask[y][x+1] == 1:
            x += 1
            print(rooms[y][x])
    elif action == 'w':
        if x > 0 and rooms_mask[y][x-1] == 1:
            x -= 1
            print(rooms[y][x])
```

But if you really want to represent your dungeon as graph, you can use this code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

raw_rooms = [
    [1,2,'n'],
    [2,3,'w'],
    [1,4,'s']
]

rooms = defaultdict(list)

for source, target, direction in raw_rooms:
    rooms[source].append([target, direction])

current_room = 1

while True:
    action = input()
    if action == 'q':
        break
    else:
        for target, direction in rooms[current_room]:
            if direction == action:
                print('I am in room {}'.format(target))
                current_room = target
```

This code uses [defaultdicts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) to store the room graph. You can also use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) to use the real graph and work with them.